# iOS Corebluetooth - Sometimes won't connect to a device until I do a network reset

Tags: ios, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been occasionally running into an issue where my app will not reconnect with a specific bluetooth LE device until I reset the network settings on my phone (I am guessing this clears the bluetooth caches). It is still able to connect to other devices fine in this state.

I am able to connect and send data with the device without any issues for a while and then I hit this and nothing seems to fix it except doing a reset.

I was wondering if anyone has run into similar issues while using Corebluetooth/CBCentralManager and found any work arounds?

Thanks!

Comment: I ran into the same stuff!

Answer (score 3):

If your device is only looking for a specific service/characteristic specified in the GATT profile, that could be the problem.  For whatever reason, Apple left out of their documentation that the Bluetooth automatically caches the GATT Profile until the bluetooth is turned off and back on.  So if you are changing the GATT on your LE device, and your phone is looking for something specific in the GATT, it may not be able to find your device. Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to clear the cache programatically, so you'll still have to manually reset bluetooth.

However, if you aren't changing the GATT profile, that whole above paragraph doesn't apply to you =P What I would keep in mind is that Bluetooth LE "slaves" (or, as Apple calls them, peripherals) can only have one connection at a time.  So your LE Device may be inadvertently connected to something else, so your app can't find it.  This could even be an app on your phone -- maybe your app is connected but doesn't display it, or (if you are testing multiple apps) another app is already connected to it.